# How to list _all_ objects in Amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

S3Client.ListObjects return only 1000 of objects. How to retrieve list of all existing objects using Amazon C# library?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

As stated already, [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) indeed requires [Listing Keys Using the AWS SDK for .NET](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingNetSDK.html):

> As buckets can contain a virtually unlimited number of keys, the
>   complete results of a list query can be extremely large. To manage
>   large result sets, Amazon S3 uses pagination to split them into
>   multiple responses. Each list keys response returns a page of up to
>   1,000 keys with an indicator indicating if the response is truncated.
>   You send a series of list keys requests until you have received all
>   the keys.

The mentioned indicator is the [NextMarker](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/P_Amazon_S3_Model_ListObjectsResponse_NextMarker.htm) property from the [ObjectsResponse Class](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Model_ListObjectsResponse.htm) - its usage is illustrated in the complete example [Listing Keys Using the AWS SDK for .NET](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingNetSDK.html), with the relevant fragment being:

```
static AmazonS3 client;
client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(
                    accessKeyID, secretAccessKeyID);

ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest();
request.BucketName = bucketName;
do
{
   ListObjectsResponse response = client.ListObjects(request);

   // Process response.
   // ...

   // If response is truncated, set the marker to get the next 
   // set of keys.
   if (response.IsTruncated)
   {
        request.Marker = response.NextMarker;
   }
   else
   {
        request = null;
   }
} while (request != null);
```

Comment: This will work but using request both as, well, the request AND as the end-of-loop marker value (when null) doesn't seem very good practice.  (Not the poster's fault as this is what the Amazon docs tell you to do.)

Answer (score 31):

Be aware that the answer above is not using the recommended API to List Objects: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html

The following snippet shows how it looks with the new API:

```
using (var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
{
    ListObjectsV2Request request = new ListObjectsV2Request
    {
          BucketName = bucketName,
          MaxKeys = 10
    };
    ListObjectsV2Response response;
    do
    {
         response = await s3Client.ListObjectsV2Async(request);

         // Process response.
         // ...

         request.ContinuationToken = response.NextContinuationToken;

    } while (response.IsTruncated);        
}
```

Comment: Why would this be an infinite loop? There will not be infinite items in S3?

Answer (score 3):

API version has been changed; so need to do as below:

```
            ListObjectsV2Request request = new ListObjectsV2Request
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                MaxKeys = 10
            };
            ListObjectsV2Response response;
            do
            {
                response = await client.ListObjectsV2Async(request);

                // Process the response.
                foreach (S3Object entry in response.S3Objects)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("key = {0} size = {1}",
                        entry.Key, entry.Size);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Next Continuation Token: {0}", response.NextContinuationToken);
                request.ContinuationToken = response.NextContinuationToken;
            } while (response.IsTruncated);
```

For full details, please see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingNetSDK.html

Answer (score 2):

Use a paginator, introduced [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-paginators-in-aws-sdk-for-net-v3-5/).  Amazon recommends these as a cleaner syntax compared to a do-while, and they take advantage of C# 8's `IAsyncEnumerable`.

```cs
IAmazonS3 S3;
CancellationToken cancellationToken;

var results = new List<S3Object>();

var paginator = S3.Paginators.ListObjectsV2(new ListObjectsV2Request
{
    BucketName = "my-bucket-name",
    Prefix = "my/prefix",
});
await foreach (var response in paginator.Responses.WithCancellation(cancellationToken))
{
    results.AddRange(response.S3Objects);
}

return results;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation the client uses pagination in the case you describe. As per documentation you should use [IsTruncated](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/P_Amazon_S3_Model_ListObjectsResponse_IsTruncated.htm) on the result... if it is `true` call [`ListObjects`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3Client_ListObjects.htm) again with correctly setup `Marker` to get the next page etc. - stop calling when `IsTruncated` returns `false`.