# List files in directory

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, xamarin

I'm using the [Amazon S3 Xamarin Component](https://components.xamarin.com/view/DataNuage.Aws.S3), the full version.  I can create buckets, get and put files within my bucket and even within foldiers.  But how do I List files in a directory that's inside of a bucket?  Or how do I list files within a bucket?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list \_all\_ objects in Amazon S3 bucket?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920804/how-to-list-all-objects-in-amazon-s3-bucket)

Comment: Looks like that's using the Amazon S3 Library and not the Xamarin Component, but I'm going to look into using that instead if I can't get this to list directories.