# How to bring 10000+ results when listing buckets with AWS C# SDK

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When trying to list all Buckets (Which is over 30000 buckets) I only get 10000 results. And I would need to receive absolutely all of them.

```
Console.WriteLine(S3.ListBucketsAsync().Result.Buckets.Count);
```

The output always returns 10000, although I know there are more.

Is there something I can modify in the request or in the config that makes me receive them all without this limitation?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

```
Console.WriteLine(S3.ListBucketsAsync().Result.HttpStatusCode.ToString());
```

Return OK;

Comment: Does `S3.ListBucketsAsync()` have any arguments, such as a page number, or continuation token?

Comment: Also please `await` an async method rather than using the `.Result` property of the task.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list \_all\_ objects in Amazon S3 bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920804/how-to-list-all-objects-in-amazon-s3-bucket)

Comment: @gunr2171 I was only able to pass CancellationToken unfortunately

Comment: @gunr2171 I'm using result just for the example.

Comment: @gunr2171 ListBucketsAsync generates a response of type ListBucketsResponse, which in turn does not have pagination or IsTruncated attribute.

Comment: Are you familiar with .Net Task? Test if the task [completed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.iscompletedsuccessfully?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-task-iscompletedsuccessfully) and investigate whether or not you need to [wait](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=net-6.0) for the task to ensure complete results.

Comment: I am familiar and the task is completed without errors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.